# Calling model function in blade brake view - Laravel

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have two installation of laravel one local and the other one on a raspberry pi. I'm using a git repository to sync.

Everything is working fine except for one thing: I have one to many relation between teacher and schools.

This is my Teacher model:

**Teacher - Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Teacher extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'teacher';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function students() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
    }

    public function school() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }
}
```

And this is the part where web version break

**Teacher - View**

```
@foreach ($teachers as $teacher)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $teacher->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $teacher->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $teacher->school->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $teacher->email }}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="teachers/{{ $teacher->id }}">View</a></td>
              </tr>
@endforeach
```

The TeacherController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Teacher;
use App\School;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreTeacher;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class TeacherController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
      $teachers = Teacher::all();
      $schools = School::all();
      return view('admin.teachers.index')
                    ->with('teachers', $teachers)
                    ->with('schools', $schools);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreTeacher $request)
    {
        $teacher = new Teacher;
        $teacher->name = $request->input('name');
        $teacher->email = $request->input('email');
        $teacher->password = $request->input('password');
        $teacher->school_id = $request->input('school_id');

        $teacher->save();

        return redirect('admin/teachers')->with('status', 'New teacher created!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
      $teacher = Teacher::findOrFail($id);
      return view('admin.teachers.show')->with('teacher', $teacher);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
      $teacher = Teacher::findOrFail($id);
      return view('admin.teachers.edit')->with('teacher', $teacher);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
      $teacher = Teacher::findOrFail($id);
      $teacher->delete();
      return redirect('/admin/teachers')->with('status', 'Teacher deleted!');
    }
}
```

this is the error:

```
in 5bdd62e78cd0ce07d649d6a0703baeeac6c5e20e.php line 21
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 1) in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/The-Film-Corner/storage/framework/views/5bdd62e78cd0ce07d649d6a0703baeeac6c5e20e.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag), 'teachers' => object(Collection), 'schools' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/The-Film-Corner/resources/views/admin/teachers/index.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'teachers' => object(Collection), 'schools' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 560
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 43
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), 'admin') in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

the most incomprehensible part is that in the local version of the app everything is working fine.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to find it in the rendered view. Look in your storage folder for 5bdd62e78cd0ce07d649d6a0703baeeac6c5e20e.php (or whatever file it references) and look for line 21 there.

Comment: Can you provide your Controller code ?

Comment: @aynber it's not so easy....the line 21  <td>{{ $teacher->school->name }}</td>

Comment: @nextt1 sure, done.

Comment: Are the databases (content) identical? Do all teachers have the school ID set?

Comment: @aynber yes, are empty

Comment: @AngusSimons Is this file exists ? `/var/www/The-Film-Corner/storage/framework/views/5bdd62e78cd0ce07d649d6a0703baeeac6c5e20e.php`

Comment: @nextt1 yes it exist.

Comment: Check ownership of the views directory and view files. The webserver should have rw permission on the views.

Comment: Thanks I solved this clearing the db and a reset of the files permissions. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `$teacher->school->name` with `$teacher->school()->name`.